# EJB 3.2 performance degradation

Tags: performance, ejb

I'm currently upgrading an EJB project from version 2.0 to version 3.2 (all Stateful). The business logic remains the same, the only thing that changes is the EJB part (replacing descriptor files with annotations, using injection points instead of traditional lookups, etc.).
From the point of view of request processing, everything seems to be working fine, the problem is with performance.
With one connected client, every request takes around 300 ms. If I add a second client, the average time jumps to 700 ms. With a third client, the average exceeds 1 sec, and so on. With the EJB 2.0 version, the processing time increases slightly (50~100ms), even with more clients, but nothing to worry about.

The degradation is pretty obvious, and I just can't figure out the reason.

I've played around with EJB timeouts, transaction types, etc, but with no luck. I've also tried profiling the server (via JMC), but could not find anything suspicious.

It is as if all requests are processed sequentially and never concurrently.

Can someone give some hints on possible causes? Is there any configuration I'm missing?

**NOTE:** The problem occurs on both WebSphere 9 and GlassFish 4.1.1, so it's clearly an application's problem.

**EDIT #1**

After checking the application's log, I can confirm that the requests are being processed sequentially, no concurrency.

Following Michael's suggestion, I looked at a thread dump and, at a given moment, there were:

- 27 RUNNABLE
- 18 TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
- 6 TIMED_WAITING (parking)
- 16 TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
- 23 WAITING (on object monitor)
- 40 WAITING (parking)

No signs of blocked threads.

Any idea?

Comment: Try to get thread dump during load test with 5+ users. I suppose there is shared resource required exclusive lock.

Comment: @Michael, I don't have much experience analyzing thread dumps. What exactly should I be looking for?

Comment: Simple way to take thread dump: jstack <pid> >> myapp.log. When you need to search/grep by "lock". There may be a lot of trash. if you can, it's worth to publish it via pastebin.

Comment: I've the thread dump, but I really don't know how to interpret it. Is there an alternative to pastebin? The SO community isn't very fond of it.

Comment: I wasn't aware of it. OK, there are a lot of Thread Dump analyzer tools, for instance: https://github.com/irockel/tda. Disclaimer: I've never used them. You need to find lock & reason of lock. Then read & analyze source code. ))

Answer (score 1):

How are you testing this?

This sounds to me like multiple clients are getting the same stateful session bean instance.

The container will serialise calls to the same SFSB instance. It's supposed to do that and if it was not happening before then maybe you had some platform dependent deployment descriptor that disabled this behaviour.

However, if you're using a test framework and all of it's clients are getting the same session then this will also make it look like you have a problem.

§4.3.13 "Serializing Session Bean Methods" of the EJB spec says:

> The container serializes calls to each stateful and stateless session
>   bean instance. Most containers will support many instances of a
>   session bean executing concurrently; however, each instance sees only
>   a serialized sequence of method calls. Therefore, a stateful or
>   stateless session bean does not have to be coded as reentrant.

If you are sharing a single SFSB instance amongst all clients then it may be appropriate to change it from @Stateful to @Singleton. Singleton EJBs give explicit reentrancy controls via the [@ConcurrencyManagement](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/ConcurrencyManagement.html) and [@Lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Lock.html) annotations. If you're completely happy with the thread safety of your EJB then you may get away with marking your bean up with:

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
public class MyStatefulSessionBeanMasqueradingAsASingleton {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm using a simulator that has several terminals (clients) configured and connects to my application, simulating closely what happens in a production environment. Both versions (EJB 2 and 3) use SFSB, the only difference is that version 2 is using a rudimentary caching system, which doesn't justify the sequential processing (IMO).

Comment: You have one or more SFSBs that are accessed by all clients?

Comment: Yes, all requests are being processed by the same SFSB.